# Group rows by similarity

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a set of 850,000 entries in a MySQL Database. Some entries are very similar, like

```
Foobar Lorem
Foobar Ipsum
Foobar Dolor
```

How can i group all entries by similarity (e.g. at least 4 equal characters). 
I can't query a specific string with a `LIKE` operator, cause I don't know all possible similar entries.

I've found a few interesting approaches (e.g. Levenshtein distance), but all the functions need at least one parameter to look for.

Any suggestions?

**/update**

It's sufficient when the beginning of the string is similar

Comment: i think the reason why you aren't finding approaches that take no parameters is that without something to look for the possibilities will grow exponentially

Comment: You could look into a [clustering algorithm](http://jonisalonen.com/2012/k-means-clustering-in-mysql/). For `k-means` you could probably pick a random word as a centroid and use the levenshtein distance to cluster them.

Comment: `GROUP BY SUBSTRING(col, 1, 6)` would group by the beginning, trim if needed.  Alternatively, go just to the first `' '` character.

Comment: @Slevin . . . If you really want answer to the question, please provide some sample data with examples of things that should be "group"ed together and others that should not be.

Answer (score 3):

you may want to try `SOUNDEX` as this is an algorithm that creates a code based on what a particular word or set of words sounds like, so any words that sound similar will be grouped here (the codes can be long with longer strings, so trim to the first 6 chars). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex

```
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(SOUNDEX(col), 1, 6)
```